# Hide "Selection Preview" caret on UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextarea

I'm having a hard time googling this one because I'm not sure what to call it but here's a screenshot.

[image: Strange selection caret on my UITextView]

The issue is that I have a large font-size user-editable UITextView. I'm creating and adding it like this:

```
UITextView *textView1 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){0,0,700,200}];
textView1.text = @"THANK YOU";
textView1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size:95.0];
textView1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textView1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.innerContainerView addSubview:textView1];
[textView1 sizeToFit];
textView1.frame = CGRectInset(textView1.frame, -20, 0);
textView1.center = (CGPoint){self.innerContainerView.frame.size.width / 2, self.innerContainerView.frame.size.height / 2};
textView1.delegate = self;
```

Everything works great until the user goes to select a specific character range. While dragging the selection handles this (mostly) empty caret appears. It seems like this would normally show you a slightly magnified preview of the text being selected but here it's useless and ugly. Is there a way to disable this tool? What's it even called?

Comment: That pop-up is called a menu controller. The menu controller is a singleton; it can be accessed as follows: [UIMenuController sharedMenuController]. Does the issue disappear with a different font or font size?

Comment: With a smaller font size the text inside the bubble is visible, it's basically showing me a preview, sometimes smaller, sometimes larger, than the actual UITextField immediately beneath it.  If the font is very large the preview doesn't fit very well (see above).

Comment: There is no such thing as a UITextArea.

Comment: Hah, you're totally right.  It's a UITextView.  I've edited the question and title.

Comment: Have you tried: `[UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;`

Comment: I have tried that, but maybe not in the right place.  I'm calling it in the UITextView's delegate method textViewDidChangeSelection:.  The method is definitely being called but that guy hangs around still.

For the record I'd rather not get rid of the UIMenuController entirely.  I'd like options like "copy" and "paste" to be available.  I just don't need this selection preview thing it does.

Comment: This cannot be removed in `UITextView`. You'll need to create a new `UIView` subclass (or `UIScrollView` subclass, as is `UITextView`) that mimics most of `UITextView`. It should conform to the `UITextInput` protocol.

However, the behaviour of this in `UITextView` seems undesirable and I highly recommend reporting an enhancement request (http://bugreport.apple.com) to better adjust the magnifier for large text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
yourTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```